# Spika-iOS : "incompatible block pointer types"

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray

I have downloaded the 'Spika' script for iOS and Android but have run into the following issue. When trying to compile I get the following error :

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(ModelMessage *__strong, ModelMessage *__strong)' to parameter of type 'NSComparator' (aka 'NSComparisonResult (^)(__strong id, __strong id)')
```

I have tried to resolve the issue by changing it to NSComparisonResult but cannot seem to get my head around what the issue is.

Here is the code :

```
NSMutableArray *removeTarget = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [result count] ; i++){

    ModelMessage *message = [result objectAtIndex:i];

    if(message.valid == NO)
        [removeTarget addObject:message];

}

for(int ii = 0; ii < [removeTarget count] ; ii++){
    [result removeObject:[removeTarget objectAtIndex:ii]];
}

NSArray *sortedAry = [result sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(ModelMessage *a, ModelMessage *b) {
    return a.modified> b.modified;
}];

int fetchNum = PagingMessageFetchNum;
if(fetchNum > sortedAry.count)
    fetchNum = sortedAry.count;

return sortedAry;

//return [sortedAry subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, fetchNum)];
}
```

The issue lies in :

```
NSArray *sortedAry = [result sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(ModelMessage *a, ModelMessage *b) {
    return a.modified> b.modified;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you running it ios 7+ ?

Comment: Hey @ViralNarshana thanks for your suggestion I was and have now fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return not a BOOL result as in your code above.
The result must be of type `NSComparisonResult` which is enum

```
enum {
  NSOrderedAscending = -1,
  NSOrderedSame,
  NSOrderedDescending
};
```

In your case the sorting block should look like that

```
NSArray *sortedAry = [result sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(ModelMessage *a, ModelMessage *b) {
    if(a.modified<b.modified)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if(a.modified>b.modified)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else 
        return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Comment: Hey @Astoria, your answer works. Although the real issue was that I was running a beta version of Xcode 6. Once I updated to GM it resolved itself. I will up vote your answer as it was actually correct.